# How do I serialize my result from my .each function?

Tags: jquery, ajax, serialization

I have been searching for hours for answers to my problem. I'm not sure im searching for the right method but here goes anyway.

I want to serialize the result i get from this:

```
$('div.text').each(function () {
   console.log($(this).attr('name') + ": " + $(this).text());
});
```

and put it serialized into my ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'send-exec.php',
    data: string,
    success: function (data) {
        if (data === 'success') {
            console.log('success');
        } else {
            console.log('fail');
        }
    }
});
```

The information that I get in the console is exactly right but i don't know how to get this serialized and working with the POST function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest creating an object and not worrying about serializing the string yourself.

The error in your serializing is that the `:` should be `=` and you would need to add `&` to separate each one.

Passing an object to `data` in $.ajax is more convenient and jQuery will serialize it for you

```
var post_data ={};
$('div.text').each(function () {
   post_data[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).text();
});

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'send-exec.php',
    data: post_data,
    ....
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably best to creat an object and fill the object inside your loop.

```
var data = {};   <!-- create object

$('div.text').each(function () {
    data[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).text();
}
```

And then you can add the object to your AJAX and send it.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'send-exec.php',
    data: data,
    success: function (data) {
        if (data === 'success') {
            console.log('success');
        } else {
            console.log('fail');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: don't stringify to send to php, would be sending only a value, not key/value. Also syntax isn't correct for the object property assignment